# When i am creating NSManageObject subclass with Xcode Editor getting errors?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Getting lots of error while creating NSManageObject subclass.[image]

Comment: Could you please add any other files where `Bowtie` is defined and a how your entity is configured in the CoreData editor, in particular the _Codegen_ option in the _Data Model Inspector_ (3rd tab in the right panel when editing the .xcdatamodel with the entity selected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this:

1. Go to Project name.xcdatamodeld
2. Select an entity
3. select Data Model inspector on the right
4. then in Class section, set **module = Current Product Module** and
   **Codegen =   Manual/none**
5. Then clean the product and restart Xcode.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Bowtie has set Module to Current Product Module and it's not None.